# iptables ACCEPT for one user

Tags: iptables

serverFault.

I'm trying to make 'specific' Wi-Fi/Server now, but I'm encountered a problem.

This iptables config doesn't work properly:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m owner —uid-owner steins -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m owner —uid-owner debian-tor -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m owner —uid-owner i2psvc -j ACCEPT
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [5:933]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1:32]
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp —dport 22 -j REDIRECT —to-ports 22
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p udp -m udp —dport 53 -j REDIRECT —to-ports 53
-A PREROUTING -i wlan0 -p tcp -m tcp —tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9040
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

WiFi incoming connection successfully routes to the Tor network, internal Proxy also works fine, but 'steins' user cannot access internet freely without Proxy. Why?

Is there is a way to unblock user traffic?

Comment: I didnt knew you could use username in iptables, you sure its not just local user on the server? as for forwarding, it become IP restriction. Thus I would make sure the steins user always got thesame internal IP to make a matching rule

Comment: Yagmoth555, this is a new user, just like debian-tor, what I created on my RPi.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some details to give accurate answer, like your network setup. But looking at your iptables OUTPUT chain setup this happens most likely because you block all kernel requests with these rules. Check the module "owner" man page:

```
   owner
       This module attempts to match various characteristics of the packet creator, for locally generated packets. This match is only valid in the OUT-
       PUT  and  POSTROUTING  chains.  Forwarded packets do not have any socket associated with them. Packets from kernel threads do have a socket, but
       usually no owner.
```

As we can see, kernel packets has socket but no owner. And you don't allow any packets without owner UID set, except for the localhost.

When you try to "access the Internet" from your user steins, most likely this involves at least DNS request. Userspace process requests kernel to resolve it with a function like gethostbyname(). Which makes kernel to send it's own packet to the DNS server. Which becomes blocked by your iptables setup. Networking also involves ARP requests which is also originating from kernel.

To resolve this you need to allow packets having sockets but no UID associated with them. This is done with --socket-exists owner option:

```
  [!] --socket-exists
          Matches if the packet is associated with a socket.
```

So add a line like this:

```
-A OUTPUT -m owner --socket-exists -j ACCEPT
```

to allow kernel originated packets. I also recommend to allow packets from 'root' user too. Because some system daemons running from root might require that too.

Also some useful advice on how to diagnose such issues, when your iptables setup doesn't works like intended. Just add a LOG action at the end of your chain in question and all dropped packets will be logged to your syslog. Like this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT DROPPED:"
```

Also, running iptables with '-L -v' switches will output you number of packets reaching each rule so you can check if it actually triggers.